# Audio through a Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I would like to implement a Bluetooth headset profile and hands-free profile on a Pi 3. I have successfully connected (via Bluetooth) my Pi 3 with a Bluetooth headset, (with built-in microphone).

Also a USB microphone is attached to Pi. Is it possible to transfer audio to and from the Pi?

I want to hear live audio from the headset microphone through the Pi's audio out and also hear audio from the USB microphone through the headset out. The same for the hands-free profile as well.

In the hands-free profile I want to speak and hear sound from the Pi, (not from the phone). Is there any way to stream live audio between the Pi and a mobile phone?

Currently I'm using Bluez, PulseAudio and oFono.

I have already implemented an A2DP profile with PulseAudio. Basic phone operations are working perfectly with oFono.

The main problem is with the audio flow to and from Pi. I have done some research tried a lot of different things, nothing works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: I want to know whether it is possible to implement HFP profile in pi. I want to hear call voice from pi and speak at pi, provided my phone is connected to pi. If it is possible could you please share the required steps and commands?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, You are able to implement A2DP correctly, but can only transfer controls but not audio when implementing HFP. I also faced the same issue and on searching, found that so many people are facing the same issue. It seems to be a problem with the internal BT adapter and got it working using an external USB BT adapter. See [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=149496&p=983263) for a discussion on the BT issue. So as a workaround to get the HFP working you can use an external BT dongle. I've just tried the audio from phone to PI but not using a mic to get audio from Pi to phone. So no comments on the mic part and you'll have to try it to find it. :)